# syntax error ehile token '=' SDCC

Tags: microcontroller, c, software, compiler, error

```
# include <at89x51.h>
# define LCDPort P1
#define RS P0_0;
#define RW P0_1;
#define EN P0_2;

void delay(int t)
 {
        int i;
    while(t>0)
      {
        i=1275;
        while(i>0) i--;
        t--;
      }
 }
  void LCDCommand(unsigned char Value)
 {
    RS=0; //here was the error//
    RW=0;
    LCDPort=Value;
    EN=1;
    delay(2);
    EN=0;
    return;
}

 void LCDData(unsigned char Value)
 {
        RS=1;
    RW=0;
    LCDPort=Value;
    EN=1;
    delay(2);
    EN=0;
    return;
}
 void LCDInit()
{
  LCDCommand(0x38);
  LCDCommand(0x06);
  LCDCommand(0x0c);
  LCDCommand(0x01);
}
 LCDPuts(char *s)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;s[i];i++) LCDData(s[i]);
}
 void main()
{
  LCDInit();

  while(1)
    {
    LCDCommand(0x01);
    delay(100);
    LCDPuts("LCD TEST");
    LCDCommand(0xc0);
    LCDPuts("www.deas.in");
    delay(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Remove the ; from the #define. Otherwise `RS=0;` becomes `P0_0;=0;`.

Comment: Enro, if you're going to seek help here, at least have the decency to ask a question. As it is, your post looks as though you couldn't be bothered to actually take the time to explain your question and expect us to just figure it out and solve your problem. Please show more respect towards us in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You have the defines:

```
#define RS P0_0;
#define RW P0_1;
#define EN P0_2;
```

Then the statement:

```
RS=0;
```

Expanded out, that equates to:

```
P0_0;=0;
```

Spot the error.

Everything after the name of a `#define` gets replaced verbatim. *That includes the semicolon on the end.*

`#define` is not a C command, it is a C pre-processor directive, and as such follows completely different semantic rules than C.